# What does "more so" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, reference

> It wasn't as if he didn't work just as hard as I did --- more so, probably.

It's just an example sentence I quoted from a dictionary. I know the definition of "more so" but does more so in this case means that he worked even harder than me?

Comment: The speaker suspects that he does.

Comment: @Mick - I do not understand your comment.  Too sophisticated for me, I expect.

Comment: Please provide the dictionary definition that accompanied the example, along with some clue about where your confusion lies.

Answer (score 1):

> ...does more so in this case means that he worked even harder than me?

Yes, but the word *probably* is important here. The speaker isn't certain that the other person works harder. The speaker is guessing about that. However, the speaker is certain that *at least* they worked equally hard.

This kind of sentence might be used when another coworker received a promotion and you didn't.

"I thought I deserved the promotion more than him. It wasn't as if he didn't work just as hard as I did --- more so, probably. However, many customers complained about his rudeness and he was often late to work."

Answer (score 0):

The ***probably*** in the end is modifying the ***more so.*** Meaning that the writer is only assuming that the person in the sentence is working more than her.

Comment: I don't think the ***probably*** is  what the question is about.